# How can I redirect to URL after variable value is loaded?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

I have an application in Node with Express and trying to successfully finish the implementation of a payment system called "Flow".

[**EDIT**]
I bypassed something very important, it's a function that wraps the functionality that is triggering after the end of the method. I tried making it async so I can wrap the functions then as a promise like someone adviced, but got some errors. I'll re-check.

```
//REALIZAR PAGO $
  app.post('/realizarPago', function(req, res){

  var amount = Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999) + 100000;
  var paymentMethod = 9;
  var urlRedirect = "https://sandbox.flow.cl/app/web/pay.php?token=";
  ...
 //Other relevant variables



 var req = https.request(options, function (res) { //<=== This one

    res.on("data", function (chunk) {
      chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    res.on("end", function (chunk) {
      ...
      //this is just a sample token that I'll later capture from response
      urlRedirect = urlRedirect+"1234567890";

    });

  });

  var postData = qs.stringify({
    'flowOrder': flowOrder,
    'amount': amount,
    ...

  });

   req.write(postData);
   res.redirect(307, urlRedirect);
   req.end();
});
```

Everything works almost fine, the problem is that **the redirect is executed before urlRedirect updates its value** in `urlRedirect = urlRedirect+"1234567890";`

I've tried with `.then()` after `res.write(postData)` executes, with no useful result. I've tried `.then()` in almost every method, I've also tried with `res` instead of `req` and viceversa. I also did some research and found an interesting thing called "waterfall" for async methods but in case of `res.on` methods can't imagine a way of encapsulating this.

What can I try next?

[**EDIT 2**]
Thanks to all of your guidance, I was able to use some promises and change the execution order. Now it's doing what I need, now it says that some parameters are missing in the https request. I'll have to fix that. The final code is:

```
//REALIZAR PAGO $
app.post('/realizarPago', async function(request, response){

  var amount = Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999) + 100000;
  var paymentMethod = 9;
   ...
  //Other relevant variables
  var urlRedirect = "https://sandbox.flow.cl/app/web/pay.php?token=";

var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  var chunks = [];

  res.on("data", (chunk) => {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });


  res.on("end", (chunk) => {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    var datos = body.toString();
     datos = JSON.parse(datos);
    var token = datos.token;
    urlRedirect = urlRedirect+token

      response.redirect(urlRedirect);
    });


});
req.end();


  var postData = qs.stringify({
    'flowOrder': flowOrder,
    'amount': amount,
    ...

  });    
req.write(postData);
req.end();
});
```

Comment: Any specific reason to update `urlRedirect` in the `end` handler?

Comment: @SujeetSinha no reason at all. It was a Postman auto-generated code that was useful for console debugging at first... thanks

Comment: I believe your redirect call should be triggered in the `res.on("end"`,

Comment: @VivekMolkar thank you, but I'm getting  `TypeError: req.redirect is not a function` , same with res instead of req

Comment: I believe you are trying to call `sandbox.flow.cl`. This is not done with `req` (that contains what comes from the browser) nor `res` (that is used to respond to the browser). You need something else entirely. You need to make a HTTP call to `sandbox.flow.cl` using a library like [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) . When this call is over and you have your data, you can then pass it to `res.send(data)` to send it back to the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put the redirect into the `end` event handler, and you also add an error handler in case the request fails and you change the name of one of the two `res` arguments so they don't conflict and you can still access both of them.  I changed the higher level one to `response` so it can be used inside the other callbacks where `res` is already defined:

```
//REALIZAR PAGO $
  app.post('/realizarPago', function(req, response){  // <== change arg name to response

  var amount = Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999) + 100000;
  var paymentMethod = 9;
  var urlRedirect = "https://sandbox.flow.cl/app/web/pay.php?token=";
  ...
 //Other relevant variables

    res.on("data", function (chunk) {
      chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    res.on("end", function (chunk) {
      ...
      //this is just a sample token that I'll later capture from response
      urlRedirect += "1234567890";
      response.redirect(307, urlRedirect);      // <== move this here
    });

  });

  req.on('error', err => {                      // <== add this
       console.log(err);
       response.sendStatus(500);
  });

  var postData = qs.stringify({
    'flowOrder': flowOrder,
    'amount': amount,
    ...

   });

   req.write(postData);
   req.end();
});
```

Comment: thank you, it doesn't work but you gave me some lights, I'm incorporating this into my solution.

Comment: @KarenCh - What exactly didn't work?  Your code is pseudo-code anyway (not full working code) so this is guidance about how to solve the problem.  The point is that you do the redirect, where you get the actual final result (in the `end` event handler).  And, you need error handling.  And, you need to avoid conflict between two nested `res` arguments so you can use both of them.